# interruption while running php file

Tags: php

this is my code in php
bt its not working problerly as required..the output is not according to this..
i m trying to run this in wamp server.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Binary Search</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        h1 {color: blue}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Computer guess number by using binary search</h1>
<form method="GET">
<?
if (empty($flag_num))
{
    $flag_num = -1;
}
if ($flag_num==-1)
{
if (empty($max_num)) $max_num = -1;
if (empty($min_num)) $min_num = -1;
$flag_num = 1;
print <<<Here
<input type="hidden" name="flag_num" value="$flag_num">
<input type="hidden" name="max_num" value="$max_num">
<input type="hidden" name="min_num" value="$min_num">
Input your hidden number: <input type="text" name="hid_num" value="$hid_num"> (1-99)
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Now let's computer guess">
Here;
}
else 
{
if ($max_num==-1 && $min_num==-1)
{
    $max_num = 100;
    $min_num = 0;
    $result_num = $hid_num;
}
else 
{
    if ($comparision == "bigger")
    {
        $min_num = $guess_num;  
    }
    else if ($comparision == "smaller")
    {
        $max_num = $guess_num;  
    }
}
$guess_num = ($max_num + $min_num)/2;
setType($guess_num,"integer");
print "Computer guess <h3> $guess_num </h3>";
if ($guess_num == $result_num)
{
    $flag_num = -1;
}
if ($flag_num == -1)
{
    print <<<Here
<input type="hidden" name="flag_num" value="$flag_num">
<h1> Congratulation, Computer win </h1>
<input type="submit" value="Next>>>" >
Here;
}
else 
{
    print <<<Here
<input type="hidden" name="flag_num" value="$flag_num">
<input type="hidden" name="max_num" value="$max_num">
<input type="hidden" name="min_num" value="$min_num">
<input type="hidden" name="guess_num" value="$guess_num">
<input type="hidden" name="result_num" value="$result_num">
<br>
Your intruction: <input type="radio" name="comparision" value="bigger"> Bigger
                 <input type="radio" name="comparision" value="smaller"> Smaller
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
Here;
}
}
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll never get any help if you just drop your complete code and expect us to fix it for you without even saying what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$_GET['flag_num']` to get the query parameter, rather than `$flag_num`. The script isn't doing anything because none of the variables have any value. Similarly, `$_GET['max_num']`, `$_GET['min_num']`, `$_GET['hid_num']`.

Comment: still its not working..i think i should make the html then uses it with help of get method.is it??

Comment: It would help to know what problems you are experiencing, just saying it doesn't work isn't good enough.